# How can I match 0 or more atoms and never give it back to backtracking?

Tags: regular-expression

I've noticed that `matchstr('hello*', '\v\a+\*=\ze%(\A|$)', 0)` returns `hello`, which means that `\*=` is not matching the literal `*`. I thought I had got the syntax wrong, but I think I've not, because:

- `matchstr('hello*', '\v\a+\*=\ze', 0)` returns `hello*`, meaning that I'm correct at using `\*=` to match 0 or 1 occurrences of a literal `*`,
- `matchstr('hello*', '\v\a+\*\ze%(\A|$)', 0)` and `matchstr('hello* world', '\v\a+\*\ze%(\A|$)', 0)` both also return `hello*`, meaning that `\*` is matching `*` and `%(\A|$)` is matching the end of string and the space respectively.

From the above observation, I understand that `matchstr('hello*', '\v\a+\*=\ze%(\A|$)', 0)` returns `hello` because `\*=` is giving up the `*` to the `\A` in `%(\A|$)`.

The question is: can I alter this behavior? If so, how?

As far as I know, what I need is known as a possessive quantifier meaning "matches the preceding atom zero times or once and don't give it up for backtracking", but the word *possessive* doesn't even appear in [`:help pattern-searches`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern-searches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found. Skiming through [`:help pattern-searches`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern-searches) I found the examples at [`perl-patterns`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns) showing exactly what I wanted.

As far as the example in the question is concerned, the solution is to wrap `\*=` in a group and apply `@>` to it: `matchstr('hello*', '\v\a+(\*=)@>\ze%(\A|$)', 0)`.

---

FYI, this was used to make [a contribution to `vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/pull/2612), the best plugin for LaTeX.